# Create a numpy array when indexes of (fixed) elements are given

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of indexes e.g. `[1,3,12]`. I want to create another array from this such that at these indexes, I get a non-zero elements e.g. 1. So in this case, with input `[1,3,12]`, I should get `[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]`. I can do it in a `for` loop, is there a  short numpy function to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With numpy you can index with lists directly:

```
a = [1,3,12]
vector = numpy.zeros(shape=max(a) + 1)
vector[a] = 1
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. It worked after tiny change `shape = max(a) + 1`.